# Checking if a record is old and deleting it

Tags: c#, mysql

How can i check in a mysql table every row to see if the timestamp is older than 10minutes and delete it if this is true using c# ?

Comment: use a stored procedure and execute it using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query'd be simple:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE timestampfield < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

This'll work in any language, as it's just a simple SQL query, and is completely independent of the front-end.

Comment: If you're working with SQL Server you'll want to use DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE timestampfield < DATEADD(minute, -10,GetDate())

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event in MySQL that runs every x-minutes and deletes the old records from the table.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS clean_log_every_10_minutes ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
ENABLE 

DO BEGIN
  DELETE FROM table1 WHERE timestampfield < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

That way the cleanup will take place fully automatic.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html